# Is it possible to open angular/Material2 Snackbar on especific DOM element?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

component: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples

I have a page that is a parent section ('#wrapper_container'). And I want to popup the snack bar in the centre of a child element of '#wrapper_element'.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

We can't use `viewContainerRef` option in order to attach the snackbar to a custom container. From Angular Material [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig), this option is:

> The view container that serves as the parent for the snackbar for the purposes of dependency injection.
> ###Note: this does not affect where the snackbar is inserted in the DOM.###

From `ComponentPortal` [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#ComponentPortal), we can found a more detailed description of `viewContainerRef`:

> Where the attached component should live in Angular's **logical** component tree. **This is different from where the component renders**, which is determined by the PortalOutlet. The origin is necessary when the host is outside of the Angular application context.

When inspecting the DOM when a snackbar is opened, we'll find the following component hierarchy:

1. **`Body`** - `<body>`
2. **`OverlayContainer`** - `<div class="cdk-overlay-container"></div>`
3. **`Overlay`** - `<div id="cdk-overlay-{id}" class="cdk-overlay-pane">`
4. **`ComponentPortal`** - `<snack-bar-container></snack-bar-container>`
5. **`Component`** - our `Snackbar`, which is opened like: `this.snackbar.open(message, action)`.

Now, what we really need to change is the position in the DOM of the `OverlayContainer`, which, according to [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#ComponentPortal), is:

> the container element in which all individual overlay elements are
> rendered.
>
> #### By default, the overlay container is appended directly to the document body.

Technically, it is possible to provide a **custom** overlay container, as described in [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#the-overlay-container), by using a custom provider:

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: OverlayContainer, useClass: AppOverlayContainer}],
 // ...
})
export class MyModule { }
```

A simple implementation would be the one posted [here](https://www.bbogdanov.dev/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container).

---

But, unfortunately, it is a **singleton** and creates a potential problem:

**`MatDialog`, `MatSnackbar`, `MatTooltip`, `MatBottomSheet` and all the components that use the `OverlayContainer` will open within this AppOverlayContainer**:

Since this situation is far from ideal, the custom provider that I've wrote (`AppOverlayContainer`) needs to change the position of the `overlaycontainer` only on demand. If not called, it will let the `overlaycontainer` to be appended to the `body`.

The code is:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
  appOverlayContainerClass = 'app-cdk-overlay-container';

  /**
   * Append the OverlayContainer to the custom wrapper element
   */
  public appendToCustomWrapper(wrapperElement: HTMLElement): void {
    if (wrapperElement === null) {
      return;
    }
    
    // this._containerElement is 'cdk-overlay-container'
    if (!this._containerElement) {
      super._createContainer();
    }

    // add a custom css class to the 'cdk-overlay-container' for styling purposes
  this._containerElement.classList.add(this.appOverlayContainerClass);
   
    // attach the 'cdk-overlay-container' to our custom wrapper
    wrapperElement.appendChild(this._containerElement);
  }

  /**
   * Remove the OverlayContainer from the custom element and append it to body
   */
  public appendToBody(): void {
    if (!this._containerElement) {
     return;
    }

    // remove the custom css class from the 'cdk-overlay-container'
    this._containerElement.classList.remove(this.appOverlayContainerClass);

    // re-attach the 'cdk-overlay-container' to body
    this._document.body.appendChild(this._containerElement);
  }

}
```

So, before opening a snackbar, we must call:

```ts
AppOverlayContainer.appendToCustomWrapper(HTMLElement).
```

method, which attaches the `overlaycontainer` to our custom wrapper element.

When snackbar closes, it is ideal to call:

```ts
AppOverlayContainer.appendToBody();
```

method, which removes the `overlaycontainer` from our custom wrapper element and re-attaches it to `body`.

Also, since `AppOverlayContainer` would be injected in our component and needs to remain a singleton, we'll provide it by using `useExisting` syntax:

```ts
providers: [
   {provide: OverlayContainer, useExisting: AppOverlayContainer}
]
```

**Example:**

If we want to display the snackbar in a custom container,  `#appOverlayWrapperContainer1`:

```html
<button mat-raised-button 
  (click)="openSnackBar(appOverlayWrapperContainer1, 'Snackbar 1 msg', 'Action 1')">
  Open Snackbar 1
</button>
<div class="app-overlay-wrapper-container" #appOverlayWrapperContainer1>
  Snackbar 1 overlay attached to this div
</div>
```

In our component `.ts` we have:

```js
import { AppOverlayContainer } from './app-overlay-container';

export class SnackBarOverviewExample {

  constructor(
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private _appOverlayContainer: AppOverlayContainer
  ) { }

  openSnackBar(
    overlayContainerWrapper: HTMLElement, 
    message: string, 
    action: string
  ) {

    if (overlayContainerWrapper === null) {
      return;
    }
  
  this.appOverlayContainer.appendToCustomWrapper(overlayContainerWrapper);

    this.snackbarRef = this._snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 2000
    });
  }
}
```

Also, we need some css that must be inserted in the app generic stylesheet:

```css
.app-cdk-overlay-container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Full code and demo are on Stackblitz, were I've implemented multiple snackbar containers:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxthzy

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The `viewContainerRef` property of `MatSnackBarConfig` will accept a `ViewContainer` to use as a place to attach it's `Portal` onto.

Getting a `ViewContainerRef` of an element can be done through a ViewChild query or by injecting it into a directive that you place on the element. The former is an easier option:

component.html:

```
<div #wrapperContainer> </div>
```

component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('wrapperContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;


ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.something = this.snackBarService.open(
      'message text',
      'button text',
      { viewContainerRef: this.container}
  );

}
```

Comment: At first i thought this would be exactly what i need but when i tried to change it, it didn't seem to do anything... It seems that there is no solution available yet (https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7764)

Comment: hmm....I knew this worked with `MatDialog`, so I figured the snack bar would work the same. I guess the two are related with their `Portal`s.You *could* open the snackbar as normal, give it a component to use as the snackbar, get a `templateRef` from said component, and then create a new `Portal` from the CDK and render the `templateRef` there, but that's a total anti-pattern. Unfortunately, you're looking at a hacky fix until this bug gets addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check their [API](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api), there's the parameter `viewContainerRef` or you can define the height with `verticalPosition`.

Comment: `verticalPosition` only accepts two values: `top` and `bottom`.

Comment: ViewContainerRef not working... It seems that there is no solution available yet (github.com/angular/material2/issues/7764)